# Multiple time ranges when searching for messages in a Kafka topic using Kafka Magic tool

Tags: apache-kafka

I created a Kafka Magic query to search for particular messages, but the query takes too long to complete because the topic is very large. 
Here is the query:

```
return Context.Headers.target == "po" 
 && Context.Message.items.quantity > 10 
 && Context.Message.items.quantity < 15;
```

To make the search faster, I want to limit the search scope by specifying time range where I expect the messages to be found. This works fine for a single timestamp range: `2020-02-20T10:00 - 2020-02-20T10:59`, but my messages can appear at the same time across several days, so I need to specify multiple time ranges.

The problem is that Kafka Magic allows only one timestamp range in the search limit: `Start Timestamp/Stop Timestamp`, and including timestamp condition in the query itself does not make it faster.

How can I overcome this problem? Is there a way to efficiently search for Kafka messages in multiple time ranges using Kafka Magic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Starting from version 2 Kafka Magic allows writing automation script for complicated scenarios. Use the Task Automation page.

In your case you can create an automation script which implements three steps:

- creates an array of time ranges
- runs the search separately for each range
- then combines results into single array

Here is an example of the script:

```
var topic = Magic.getTopic('My cluster', 'my-topic-name');

var mySearchQuery = function (context) {
    return context.Headers.target == "po"
        && context.Message.items.quantity > 10
        && context.Message.items.quantity < 15;
};

var timeRanges = [
    { start: '2020-02-18T13:14:32', end: '2020-02-18T13:16:32' },
    { start: '2020-02-19T13:14:32', end: '2020-02-19T13:16:32' },
    { start: '2020-02-20T13:14:32', end: '2020-02-20T13:16:32' }
];

var messages = [];

for (var i = 0; i < timeRanges.length; i++) {

    var minTimestamp = timeRanges[i].start;
    var maxTimestamp = timeRanges[i].end;

    var rangeMessages = topic.search(true, 10, mySearchQuery, minTimestamp, maxTimestamp);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(messages, rangeMessages)
}

return messages;
```

In a similar way you can run even more complex jobs, for example sending found messages to another Kafka topic for re-processing.

See details in the docs: https://www.kafkamagic.com/automation/#searching-for-messages-in-a-topic